# Java: Employee Hierarchy Formatting Error of the toString(s)

Tags: java, inheritance, syntax, formatting, hierarchy

Hello so I had to make a superclass called Employee. Then a CommissionEmployee2 class (person is an employee with a first name, last name, and SSN. AND this type of employee earns commission) that inherited from Employee2. But when I run the test program, there is a formatting error from the toStrings. P.S Sorry about the weird formatting from copying and pasting the code!

```
//return String representation of Employee Object

public String toString()
{
return String.format("%s: %s %s%n%s: %s%n%s" , "employee" , getFirstName(), getLastName(), "social security number" , getSocialSecurityNumber());
}

}
```

Here is the toString written in CommissionEmployee2.java

```
//return String representation of CommissionEmployee copied from the book

public String toString()
{
return String.format("%s %s%n%s: %.2f%n%s: %.2f" , "commission employee" , super.toString(), "gross sales" , getGrossSales(), "commission rate" , getCommissionRate());
}
}
```

Comment: next time, a minimal example would be nice. most of the code didn't have anything to do with the problem

Answer (score 1):

You have 6 %s fields but only 5 parameters in this line:

```
return String.format("%s: %s %s%n%s: %s%n%s" , "employee" , getFirstName(), getLastName(), "social security number" , getSocialSecurityNumber());
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have two classes:

The first one is Employee2 with the following `toString()` implementation:

```
@Override 
public String toString()
{
    return String.format("%s: %s %s%n%s: %s%n%s" , "employee" , getFirstName(), getLastName(), "social security number" , getSocialSecurityNumber());
}
```

On a closer look you can see that the first paramater contains `%s` 6 times, but you have only 5 further arguments, so one argument is missing.

In the second class `CommissionEmployee2`the `toString()`implementation looks like:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return String.format("%s %s%n%s: %.2f%n%s: %.2f" , "commission employee" , super.toString(), "gross sales" , getGrossSales(), "commission rate" , getCommissionRate());
}
```

Here you also declared 6 placeholders and you pass a parameter for all those placeholders which would be perfectly fine. BUT you call the `toString()`of the parent class as the second parameter (`super.toString()`) which will call the broken `toString()`-method mentioned above. Thus you receive an exception.

Further readings:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html